# Keep style of button after click

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button. Initial background color is X. When I hover on the button, background color changes to Y. All fine. But when I click the button, background color changes back to X. I want it to keep color of Y. How can I do it?

```css
#submitStarted {
  border: solid 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #D94C27;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  font-weight: 450;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#submitStarted:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #C92A00;
}
```

```html
<input id="submitStarted" type="submit" value="Get Started">
```

Comment: simply put `#submitStarted:focus` with `:hover` style

Comment: @Bhuwan Still. Once I click, button's background color changes.

Comment: @TalRofe Do you mean, if you click the button, the color stays color Y, but if you move the mouse out, the color is changed back to X?

Comment: When I hover the button: color is Y. when I click the button: color is X (although cursor is still on the button)

Comment: @TalRofe Not on my computer.

Answer (score 4):

It's called focus state, you also need to add `#submitStarted:focus` with `#submitStarted:hover` to keep same color as hover, but it will be removed after you click out side the button.

```css
#submitStarted {
  border: solid 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #D94C27;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  font-weight: 450;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#submitStarted:hover,
#submitStarted:focus,
#submitStarted.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #C92A00;
}
```

```html
<input 
id="submitStarted" 
type="submit" 
value="Get Started" 
onclick="this.classList.add('active')">
```

---

If you want it to stay the same even after removing focus, you need to play with `classes` and some `JS`

```
onclick="this.classList.add('active')"
```